# Custom IE7 & Below Detecting via CSS

Tags: html, css

I have recently decided to completely drop support for IE7 and below for a lot of different reasons. What I wanted is for when the site is viewed in IE7 or below a message saying "Your browser is out of date. Click here to update."

Below is my take on this within the current skeleton I will (hopefully) be using for all my future projects. I know its messy but it works, just wanted to make sure its safe to use and if I have missed out on anything, feedback and bug spotting would be highly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/JcZjY/

Cheers!
Tom.

Comment: *"when the site is viewed in IE7 or below"* - so why not use `<!--[if lte IE 7 ]><html class="no-js lte-ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->`instead of the first two lines? Or  `<!--[if lt IE 8 ]><html class="no-js lt-ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->` like the message uses?

Comment: Slightly updated version (removed unnecessary IE conditional classes on the "html" element, removed the IE conditional tag from the actual message element and just used CSS to hide it from none IE browsers), better? http://jsfiddle.net/RprW3/

Answer (score 0):

Aside what's already been stated in the comments, it looks fine to me. If you'll be using HTML5 elements, don't forget to use [HTML5shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) or HTML5shiv(they're the same) to keep everything working in IE8.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Awesome, makes me feel more comfortable using it haha. I am using that in line 15 am I not?

http://jsfiddle.net/RprW3/

Comment: Yep, line 15 is cool. I usually place it after my jQuery link, and I link to my CSS right after it.